# How to watch the content of a container (eq: std::vector) with the debugger of Microsoft's C++ extension in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm on MacOS, and I'm using the C/C++ extension for vscode from Microsoft. When debugging, I can't watch the content of the STL containers, (for example, the elements of a std::vector). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csZqL.png) is a picture of how the debugger looks.

This is my `launch.json` file.

```
{
 
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++-9 - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++-9 build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed that by using clang it shows the elements of the std::vectors. Does anybody know why with g++ this doesn't work?

Comment: Please add images directly into the post for future reference, external links may expire.